# How to make a local variable global in R using Shiny?

Tags: r, scope, shiny, global-variables, local-variables

This is my first time using Shiny so sorry if this is too basic.

I have a global function called `some_global_function()` and I call it whenever the `actionButton` called `ok_input` is pressed. This creates a local variable called `algorithm_output`.

Now, I want to be able to access that variable whenever *another* `actionButton` (`ok_means`) is pressed, but without calling the function `some_global_function()` again.

Is there a way to do it? The code would be something like this:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  out_plots <- eventReactive(input$ok_input, {

    #### I call the function here and this is the variable I want
    #### to make global ########################################
    algorithm_output = some_global_function(3, 2, 1)

    do.call("grid.arrange", c(algorithm_output$indexes, nrow=3))
  })

  output$indexes <- renderPlot({
    out_plots()
  })

  out_means <- eventReactive(input$ok_means, {
    k = as.integer(input$k)

    #### I want to access the variable here ################
    matplot(algorithm_output$means[[k-1]], type = "l", lty=1)
    ########################################################

  })
  output$means <- renderPlot({
    out_means()
  })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create the variable outside any sub-function and update its value using `<<-`. This variable will be global per each session.

```R
server <- function(input, output) {

  # init variable here
  algorithm_output <- NULL

  out_plots <- eventReactive(input$ok_input, {

    # to modify a global variable use <<- instead of <- or =
    algorithm_output <<- some_global_function(3, 2, 1)

    do.call("grid.arrange", c(algorithm_output$indexes, nrow=3))
  })

  output$indexes <- renderPlot({
    out_plots()
  })

  out_means <- eventReactive(input$ok_means, {
    k = as.integer(input$k)

    # you can get access to the updated value of your variable
    matplot(algorithm_output$means[[k-1]], type = "l", lty=1)

  })
  output$means <- renderPlot({
    out_means()
  })
}
```

Comment: Emphasis on **"update" its value using `<<-`**! That is, DO NOT use the `<<-` operator to assign a variable value for the first time. When a variable does not exist yet, this operator will assign the variable to the global environment. Especially in Shiny apps this might have unintended consequences because global variables in Shiny apps are shared between users / across different sessions!!!

Comment: @Brunox13, Thanks for your suggestion. So how should we assign a global variable?  I used something like this to avoid the problem you have mentioned: `if(!exists(deparse(substitute(dataGlobal)))) {
  dataGlobal <- NULL
}`